# Share memory between Powershell and C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell

I'm developing a log search software by C#, and the underlayer of the software is achieved by powershell. There are two theards, one thread invoke powershell to search log, the log search function is achieved by powershell and it will give me the result when finishing executing the powershell.  But i want to get the log realtime. I want the powershell put the logs that has been searched to a queue. and another thread of C# to get the result from the queue. I have tried write the logs that powershell has get to a file, and C# thread read the file. but it faild, because the file is occupied by another process(powershell). Now I want to share memory between powershell and C#, that means powershell can operate the C# variable so that i can put logs to the queue when powershell is searching logs. Could you please kindly tell me how can I achieve it?  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here.  First, you don't have to use PowerShell's file output commands (Out-File/Set-Content).  You can use the .NET FileStream/StreamWriter classes directly from PowerShell which allows you to control the FileAccess/FileShare options.  Second, you could create a ConcurrentQueue (or BlockingCollection) and give that to PowerShell to write into.  Third, you could use MSMQ.  Fourth, although I haven't personally tried it, I don't see why the .NET memory mapped functionality wouldn't work in PowerShell.  The last two options seem like overkill to me.  :-)

Comment: Second, you could create a ConcurrentQueue (or BlockingCollection) and give that to PowerShell to write into. how could I share the BlockingCollection between Powershell and C#?

Comment: in powershell, i have the following code;  `code`while(!stream.end) {     readline  and write the string to blockingcollection} `code` ;   then how can I share the blockingcollection between powershell and C#

Comment: If you are using the PowerShell utility class use `Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("BlockingColl", blockingCollection);`.  Then in your PowerShell you can reference the `$BlockingColl` variable that you have created in that session.